# My scrollbar isn't displaying in Chrome, but is displayed in other major browsers

Tags: javascript, css, html

The link to the page in question is: https://rescueform.org

The overflow for the main content area is set to scroll, and is scrolling properly, however the vertical scroll bar is not visible in Google Chrome. The scroll bar does display properly in IE, Firefox, etc.

Also, I'm new to the site and I'm not sure if it's required to post the code in this post. I'm hoping that you will view the source code using your developer tools so that you can see the differences between the browsers. My main CSS file is named styles.css.

Comment: It's not required to post the code, but you'll be much more likely to get an answer if you post the code here, and even more so if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: it would be better to post code generally, because links go out of date (especially if you fix them!) however since you don't know where the issue is, and the page includes a lot of code in this case ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in "indexStyles.css" you have

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Google chrome always displays a (disabled) scroll bar when `overflow-scroll` is enabled. So I have to use another overflow setting like `overflow-auto`. VERY annoying, Chrome. Other browsers do live in this century.